# Split text into list of words contains only letters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split a text into a list of words that a word should contain only letters.
I tried this pattern `[^a-zA-Z]+` like below:

```cs
var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z]+", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);
var words = regex.Split(text).Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w))
```

When the input is `This is a t3st`, it returns `["This", "is", "a", "t", "st"]` but I'm looking for `["This", "is", "a"]` result.

I implemented it in this way:

```cs
 var words = text.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Where(str => str.All(char.IsLetter))
                 .ToList();
```

However, looking for a regex solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know C# in particular, but this should work (should be matched against the string):

```
(?<=^| )          # Beginning of line or preceding space
(?:               # 
  (?=[a-z])       #                        ...which is a letter
  .               # Match any character...
)+                # 1 or more times
(?=               # followed by
  \.?             # a literal dot at the end of the word, optionally
  (?: |$)         # End of line or succeeding space
)                 #
```

Comment: Nice explanation, the only problem is for words like `spl!tter`, it returns `spl` and `tter`

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour Updated. See if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, marked as the accepted answer.  `\b(?:(?=[a-zA-z]).)+\b` pattern matches the last word that ends with a dot, like `this is a test.` matches `["this", "is", "a", "test"]`. This pattern `(?<=^| )(?:(?=[a-zA-Z]).)+(?= |$)` ignores `"test"` and return `["this", "is", "a"]`. I will give an upvote if your regex fixes the dot problem.

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour `"This is. a test."` should be parsed as `["This", "is", "a", "test"]`, correct? If so, see updated answer. Otherwise, replace the last positive lookahead with `(?= |\.?$)`.

Answer (score 1):

Matching words that only consist of chars A-Za-z and optionally end with a dot:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?=\.?(?!\S))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `[A-Za-z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z
- `(?=` Postive lookahead, assert that to the right is

  - `\.?(?!\S)` Match an optional dot followed by a whitespace boundary
- `)` Close the lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gjupUe/1).

Matching words that only consist of chars A-Za-z:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oj7GfL/1).

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you did it this way

```
var words = regex.Split(text)
             .Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w) && Regex.IsMatch(w, "^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: If I run this, I still get the same output as in the question, i.e. `words` includes `t` and `st`. Why do you think this would exclude `t` and `st`? The `IsMatch` call will always return true in this scenario.

Comment: ` text = "This is a t!st this is a t3st"; `
` text.Split(" ").Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w) && Regex.IsMatch(w, "^[a-zA-Z]+$")) `  outputs exactly what the Q is asking for.